# Mirroring on not jailbroken iPad 1

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video-capture, mirroring

I need mirroring in my app, but iPad 1, which is not jailbroken, does not support it. Is there any way to use mirroring in my app, without affecting other applications (within the sandbox)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iPad one you can send content to a projector but only from your app.  i.e. you cannot mirror springboard or other apps.

Look at the documantation for UIScreen and the notifications it sends out when a new screen attaches.  You will need to create a seprate UIWindow to control the content for that screen.

Here is some opensource code that handles the whole process.  I haven't used this stuff my self but looks good: http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/123

Comment: The Touchcentric code is great, teaches you a bunch of stuff, but see Apple's docs for how to coexist with latest iOS and iPad2.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that with iOS 4.3 and iPad2, it is much easier - almost default - to mirror the screen:

"On compatible devices, iOS will automatically mirror the display when an external screen is attached. If you do not wish your application's contents to be mirrored, your application must present alternate content on the external display in place of the default content. To do so, use the normal process for displaying content on an external display as described in Displaying Content on an External Display in the View Programming Guide for iOS."

[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1738/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010848](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1738/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010848)

To develop a solution for all devices, see Apple's doc:

[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH4-SW9](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH4-SW9)

Sample code:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ExternalDisplay/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

your iPad does support multiple outputs, but you need to program them yourself. You need to create a second UIWindow and show what you want to show on the 2nd diplay in that UIWindow.